# jpa children size performance

Tags: hibernate, jpa

In my web application I have an Object with a OneToMany relationship with Child. 
When selecting my Objects I execute the following query:

```
from Object o
```

and then i should print for every object how many children it has with

```
// Foreach
object.children.size()
```

Assuming the object has a lot of children (let's say 30'000);
Is it a waste of resources calling size() or the ORM framework (in my case Hibernate) will take care of that without loading all the children?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using JPA (the standard):**

- Your @OneToMany relationship is by default lazy-loaded (i.e. default value for fetch=FetchType.LAZY).  But calling `Entity.getCollection().size()` would trigger lazy loading to retrieve all of the child collection - so yes, it would be fairly slow, unless you needed to operate on all/most elements anyway.  Note: for all (sane) implementations of JPA, this will NOT issue 30,000 seperate queries - it will issue one query that returns 30,000 rows in the result set.
- If you need most elements or you wanted to cache in advance change to `@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)`
- The common way do obtain data statistics without retrieving every single object is simply to use JPQL via `EntityManager.getQuery()/getTypedQuery()/getNamedQuery()` (or even SQL via `getNativeQUery()`).  This is quite simple and highly performant:

> ```
> int empSize = em.createQuery("SELECT SIZE(d.employees) FROM Department d")     
>                  .getSingleResult();
> ```

```
OR ALTERNATIVELY

// Pre-compiled query placed against entity class for highest performance   
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name="Department.EmployeeSize",
                query="SELECT SIZE(d.employees) FROM Department"),
    ... // other named queries
})
@Entity
public class Department {

    ...

}

// Then to use the query:    
int empSize = em.createNamedQuery("Department.EmployeeSize", Integer.class)     
                 .getSingleResult();
```

- You can enable level 2 caching.    [JPA Caching Summary](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/caroljmcdonald/archive/2009/08/21/jpa-caching)

  To statically configure level 2 caching:

> ```
> Map propertiesMap = new HashMap();
> // Valid values are ALL, NONE, ENABLE_SELECTIVE, DISABLE_SELECTIVE
> propertiesMap.add("javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode", "ENABLE_SELECTIVE");
> EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPUName", propertiesMap);
> ```

```
ALTERNATIVELY use persistence.xml:

<persistence-unit name="EmployeeService">
    ...
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>

</persistence-unit>
```

Then mark which entities should be automatically cached in the level 2 cache:

```
@Cacheable(true)
@Entity
public class Employee {
    ...
}
```

- Can also configure caching dynamically, as part of a particular query

**Using Proprietary approach (e.g. Hibernate "Extra-Lazy" collections):**

- Same performance as simply issuing JPQL/SQL query
- Save a couple of lines of code (@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection( EXTRA ) annotation v @NamedQuery annotation and execution)
- Not standard - JPA trained developers won't know about it
- Not portable - can only be used with that vendor.  There is an industry trend towards standard JPA, away from proprietary features.  Many different JPA implementations are out there.

Answer (score 2):

It's always good idea to enable log messages in your JPA implementation and see what DB queries are really sent to the DB. In your case I would say that ORM will probably lazily-load all objects, so it will be very inefficient.

Comment: So what would be your solution if I want to have the number of children for every Object?

Comment: @ianaz Do what you would do with plain SQL. You can for instance write a query that returns Objects together with counts, eg `"from Object o, (select count(*) from Child where parent.id = o.id)"`. It will be still inefficient , but better than counting on Java side. Alternatively you can split the query to two queries, one that reads all objects `"from Object o"` and another one that groups all children by parent and returns the count eg, `"select count(*) from Child group by parent.id"` and process it.

Comment: Edit: the last query should be `"select parent.id, count(*) from Child group by parent.id"`

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate has a special feature called "extra lazy" collections that will do exactly what you just suggested.  Meaning if you call `size()` on one of these extra-lazy collections it will return the number of children in memory if the collection has already been initialized, but will query the database for `count` if the collection has not yet been initialized.  The intent is to avoid initializing very large collections until absolutely necessary.  Other examples of things extra-lazy does include handling `Collection.contains` / `Map.containsKey` calls, `Map.get` calls, `List.get(int)`, etc calls.

To mark a collection as extra-lazy with annotations you'd say `@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyCollection( EXTRA )`